# DB Error: syntax error in civicrm/contribute/transact

Tags: sql

I'm getting the above error reported and I have no idea where to look to solve it.

The URL generating the error is http://adpca.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=3

The log / stacktrace follows:

`May 14 20:37:47  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )`

```
[code] => -2
[message] => DB Error: syntax error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] =>
```

SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id -- and many more fields
FROM civicrm_contact contact_a 
LEFT JOIN civicrm_address `1-address` ON (`1-address`.contact_id = contact_a.id AND `1-address`.is_primary = 1)
LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone `1-phone-1` ON contact_a.id = `1-phone-1`.contact_id AND ( `1-phone-1`.phone_type_id = '1' OR `1-phone-1`.phone_type_id IS NULL )  AND ( `1-phone-1`.is_primary = 1 )
LEFT JOIN civicrm_location_type `1-location_type` ON (  ( `1-address`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id ) OR ( `1-phone-1`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id ) )
LEFT JOIN civicrm_value_contact_additional_info_1 ON civicrm_value_contact_additional_info_1.entity_id = `contact_a`.id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_website `website--url` ON (`website--url`.contact_id = contact_a.id AND `website--url`.website_type_id =  )  WHERE  ( contact_a.id = '2' )   LIMIT 0, 25
[nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  WHERE  ( contact_a.id = '2' )   LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => 
SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id -- and many more fields
FROM civicrm_contact contact_a 
LEFT JOIN civicrm_address `1-address` ON (`1-address`.contact_id = contact_a.id AND `1-address`.is_primary = 1)
LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone `1-phone-1` ON contact_a.id = `1-phone-1`.contact_id AND ( `1-phone-1`.phone_type_id = '1' OR `1-phone-1`.phone_type_id IS NULL )  AND ( `1-phone-1`.is_primary = 1 )
LEFT JOIN civicrm_location_type `1-location_type` ON (  ( `1-address`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id ) OR ( `1-phone-1`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id ) )
LEFT JOIN civicrm_value_contact_additional_info_1 ON civicrm_value_contact_additional_info_1.entity_id = `contact_a`.id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_website `website--url` ON (`website--url`.contact_id = contact_a.id AND `website--url`.website_type_id =  )  WHERE  ( contact_a.id = '2' )   LIMIT 0, 25
[nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  WHERE  ( contact_a.id = '2' )   LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id -- and many more fields
FROM civicrm_contact contact_a 
LEFT JOIN civicrm_address `1-address` ON (`1-address`.contact_id = contact_a.id AND `1-address`.is_primary = 1)
LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone `1-phone-1` ON contact_a.id = `1-phone-1`.contact_id AND ( `1-phone-1`.phone_type_id = '1' OR `1-phone-1`.phone_type_id IS NULL )  AND ( `1-phone-1`.is_primary = 1 )
LEFT JOIN civicrm_location_type `1-location_type` ON (  ( `1-address`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id ) OR ( `1-phone-1`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id ) )
LEFT JOIN civicrm_value_contact_additional_info_1 ON civicrm_value_contact_additional_info_1.entity_id = `contact_a`.id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_website `website--url` ON (`website--url`.contact_id = contact_a.id AND `website--url`.website_type_id =  )  WHERE  ( contact_a.id = '2' )   LIMIT 0, 25  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  WHERE  ( contact_a.id = '2' )   LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6]"]
)

May 14 20:37:47  [info] $backTrace =
    #0 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(235): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
    #1 internal function: CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
    #2 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
    #3 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
    #4 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
    #5 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
    #6 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...")
    #7 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
    #8 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
    #9 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
    #10 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
    #11 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
    #12 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1192): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...", TRUE)
    #13 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4353): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
    #14 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(1644): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::apiQuery((Array:1), (Array:19), (Array:0))
    #15 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php(2343): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::getHierContactDetails("2", (Array:23))
    #16 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php(226): CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::setProfileDefaults("2", (Array:23), (Array:0))
    #17 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(478): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main->setDefaultValues()
    #18 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
    #19 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main), "display")
    #20 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main), "display")
    #21 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
    #22 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
    #23 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
    #24 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
    #25 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
    #26 internal function: civicrm_invoke("contribute", "transact")
    #27 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
    #28 /usr/home/adpca/public_html/adpca.org.737/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
    #29 {main}

Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any more detailed information in the CiviCRM log file in files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/ ?

Comment: This error doesn't appear when I click the link now.  I'm guessing you fixed it.  If so, please post the answer to a) help the community and b) earn some easy Stack Exchange reputation points!

Comment: Jon's comment that the error seems fixed surprised me as I've done nothing - so i clicked the link myself & still get the error. But, of course, I'm logged in. I logged out and don't get the error. So, it only happens for registered users.

Comment: I have managed to get additional information but it's too big to post here. I have put the entry from the log file in [http://adpca.org/debuglog.txt](http://adpca.org/debuglog.txt).

Comment: It looks like the faulting SQL is the join  LEFT JOIN civicrm_website `website--url` ON (`website--url`.contact_id = contact_a.id AND `website--url`.website_type_id =  ) - obviously this is missing a value. @JonG, @davejenx.

Comment: @DaveR. Two things: That log isn't too long to post here - the preferred method is to update your question.  Second - does the error go away if you remove the website field from the profile?  In the profile, maybe check to make sure the website type you selected isn't a disabled one?

Comment: Hi, @JonG. I appreciate your help on this and have updated the question with an edited version of the log as the original was pretty unreadable. Removing the website field solved the problem.  Thank you.